# markitup wysiwyg with a standard HTML form

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

I'm trying to use the markitup editor on my site and I'm having a problem trying to figure out what I need to do to submit the text area to my server side script. I'm guessing there is something simple that needs to be done but my lack of JS/JQuery knowledge is making it really hard to find a answer

The editor works fine, I just want to use my own form and submit button with it, however when I try to submit the form I don't get any of the textarea data in my script.

Any idea what I need to do? This is the min that works (before submit)

```
In the Head of my HTML
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            <!--
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#markItUp").markItUp(mySettings);
            });
            -->
        </script>   

And the body:

    <form id="postpreview" name="newpost" action="/someurl" method="POST" />
    <input type="hidden" name="key1" value="val1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="key2" value="val2" />
    <textarea name="text" id="markItUp"></textarea>
    <input id="SubmitPost" type="image" value="Continue" name="Doit" class="preview" src="/img/somimage" />
    </form>
```

As I said, everything prior to the submit works but once I submit I don't get anything for the form data element "text".

I tried doing this in the head:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            <!--
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#markItUp").markItUp(mySettings);
                $("#SubmitPost").click(function(){
                    data = markItUp.textarea.value;
                    $.post("scripturl",{ key1: "value1", key2: "value2", text: data });
                });
            });
            -->
    </script>
```

I've also tried:

```
        <script type="text/javascript" >
            <!--
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#markItUp").markItUp(mySettings);
                $("#postpreview").submit(function(){
                    var data = $("#markItUp").html();
                    $.post("live",{ func: "posting", text: data });
                    return false;
            });
        });
        -->
    </script>
```

And I have no luck - the last attempt above just disabled the form (so clicking on the submit or preview buttons did nothing).

Any ideas? I guessing its really simple to use my own form but I have no clue how to do it.

TIA!

Comment: It didn't work for me, too. Every elements' values in form sent well by both post and get method, but the markitup covered textarea didn't send. I use python simple cgi server.

Answer (score 0):

If you set it up for textareas:

```
$("textarea").markItUp(mySettings);
```

You don't have to do anything special to get the form to submit to your script.  Just put the destination in the action attribute:

```
<form name="whatever" method="POST" action="SCRIPT_URL">
```

Comment: I keep thinking its something simple so I was hoping you were right, but it didn't work. I put in the head

      <script type="text/javascript" >
       <!--
       $(document).ready(function() {
        $("textarea").markItUp(mySettings);
       });
       -->
      </script> 

And made (the only) textarea on the page

  <textarea name="text"></textarea>

And although the form submits again there is no form data for "text" :(

Comment: you might try changing the ID of the textarea to "text" as well.

Comment: No, that didn't work either. I can't believe how difficult this is proving to be. I especially can't believe they don't have a example on their own site to use a normal form :)

Comment: It didn't work for me, too. Every elements' values in form sent well by both post and get method, but the markitup covered textarea didn't send. I use python simple cgi server.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure to use markitup.min.js file

Comment: Since, in according to the OP, the editor works fine, I don't think that's the issue.